# What's the difference between admin.b360 and developer.api Autodesk's services?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

I'm trying to implement Forge API endpoints wrapper and I faced with situation, where I can create user via this endpoint https://developer.api.autodesk.com/hq/v1/accounts/:account_id/users but I can't find endpoint for removing users (not inactivation). I found that for user deleting WebUI of BIM360 actually using https://admin.b360.eu.autodesk.com/users/:user_id/destroy endpoint, but I can't find description of this endpoint anywhere. What's the difference between developer's API and admon.b360 stuff?

Comment: Where did you see https://admin.b360.eu.autodesk.com/users/:user_id/destroy?

Comment: @EasonKang Just opened Chrome Dev Tools (F12) and found that request in Network tab.

Comment: I replied to the below

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find that endpoint on our API documentation. If you only see it under the dev tools, it could be an internal endpoint of the BIM360 services that can only be accessed by BIM360 itself.

Commonly, user-accessible BIM360 APIs are exposed under the base URL https://developer.api.autodesk.com/. If you don't see it listed on the Forge BIM360 API documentation, it means the function you're looking for is not available at this moment, unfortunately.

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/